# I'm getting 11.547 kVA, but the answer is supposed to be 10 kVA. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: power, transformer, kirchhoffs-laws, math

> A 3-phase transformer bank consists of three identical 2300/230 V, 15 kVA single-phase transformers connected in delta/delta. The bank supplies a 20 kVA, unity p.f. 3-phase load. If one of the single-phase transformer develops a fault and is removed, the load carried by each of the two transformers now operating in open delta will be?

I divided the total load kVA by \$\sqrt{3}\$ to get the load kVA shared by each transformer in the V-V connection. In the solution, they just divided by 2(?). Am I in the wrong here?

Comment: a) Do voltages or phases change when one transformer is removed? b) What is the load on each transformer with all three working? c) *Why* divide by \$\sqrt 3\$?

Comment: When one transformer is removed, the supply voltage or the phase sequence doesn't change. The load on each transformer with all three working is 20/3 KVA.

Comment: To supply the same load, the line current and line voltage must be the same. Now in V-V connection, the phase current is the same as the line current. So the power supplied by each transformer in V-V is √3 times that supplied by each transformer when all three were working. That is why I divided the load KVA by √3  , because √3 times 20/3 is 20 divided by √3.

Comment: (I wouldn't be surprised if it was 10 kW, 11.547 kVA each.)

Comment: The answer can't be 10 KW if the load is unity power factor. Is my answer correct then?

Answer (score 0):

You're right.

20kVA so the load on each secondary is 6.67kVA

When you lose one transformer, the remaining two each pick up all current the missing transformer was passing but the angle is offset by 60 degrees so it adds to 11.547.